# Runtime Error 13 type mismatch - Selecting the sheet name in Workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I am struck on type mismatch error for Selecting the sheet name in Workbook. All sheet name have stored in the string array. I search in google and stackoverflow but didn't get any idea. here is the part of the code

```
Dim Tran(5) As String
    Dim celltext As String

    For i = 1 To 5
        celltxt = ActiveSheet.Range("K" & i).Text
        Tran(i) = celltext

    Next i
For i = 1 To 5


                wb4.Sheets(Tran(i)).Select 'problem line
                Set wb4sheet = wb4.Sheets(Tran(i))

                Set r = wb4sheet.UsedRange.Find("Payout Date")
                    j = wb4sheet.UsedRange.Row

                    Set rn = Range(r.Address, Cells(j, r.Column))
                Set b = wb4sheet.UsedRange.Find("Actual Paid in Principal")
                    Col1 = b.Column
```

Comment: Apart from the typo with `celltxt` which has been mentioned in the current answers, your next line will fail because `sName` has not been assigned a value.  **Learn to love `Option Explicit`.**

Answer (score 1):

You assign value from `ActiveSheet.Range("K" & i).Text` to `celltxt`, but when assigning it to `Tran(i)` you use `celltext`. It's typo that could be solved by using `Option Explicit` at the beginning of the module.

Comment: i did it even though same error occurred on the  problem line

Comment: You did what? Please, be more specific. Do you know you can debug your code by pressing F8 and in that way you can check what are values of your variables? You should check what values are in `Tran`.

Answer (score 1):

See edit in code beneath. I removed celltext, as there is no need for such an intermediate string. Also you declared your array wrong. I made it start at 1, instead of 0, and run to 5, just like your i does.

Also it is good practice to have a next for loop use a different letter, for exmaple j.

```
Dim Tran(1 to 5) As String
Dim i as integer
Dim k as integer


    For i = 1 To 5
        Tran(i) = ActiveSheet.Range("K" & i).Text       
    Next i

For k = 1 To 5
                wb4.Sheets(Tran(k)).Select 'problem line
                Set wb4sheet = wb4.Sheets(sName)

                Set r = wb4sheet.UsedRange.Find("Payout Date")
                    j = wb4sheet.UsedRange.Row

                    Set rn = Range(r.Address, Cells(j, r.Column))
                Set b = wb4sheet.UsedRange.Find("Actual Paid in Principal")
                    Col1 = b.Column
next k
```